# Preserve the size of dragged item while dragging it over another item in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, dnd-kit

I am creating an app where different sentences can be ranked using drag and drop feature using react. My problem is whenever an item of smaller size is dragged over item of larger size, the smaller item streches. When an item with larger size is dragged over item with smaller size , the larger item shrinks.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

I need to preserve the size of the dragged item when it is dragged.

Any idea how it can be done?

my code is as follow:

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DndContext, closestCenter,useTransform } from '@dnd-kit/core';
import {
  arrayMove,
  SortableContext,
  verticalListSortingStrategy

} from '@dnd-kit/sortable';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { SortableItem } from './SortableItem.jsx';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [ranking, setRanking] = useState([
    "I dont understand why people dont accept that no matter what,Boys will be boys and men will be men",
    "She is such a drama queen.",
    "Don't be a sissy.",
    "Man is a better driver than women.",
    "God is a man."
  ]);

  function handleDragEnd(event) {
    console.log('Drag');
    const { active, over } = event;
    console.log('Active:' + active.id);
    console.log('Over :' + over.id);

    
    if (active.id !== over.id) {
      setRanking((items) => {
        const activeIndex = items.indexOf(active.id);
        const overIndex = items.indexOf(over.id);
        console.log(arrayMove(items, activeIndex, overIndex));
        return arrayMove(items, activeIndex, overIndex);
      });
    }
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <DndContext collisionDetection={closestCenter} onDragEnd={handleDragEnd} >
        <h3 style={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold' }} align="center">
          Rank the following sentences from most to least sexist.
        </h3>
        <div className="frame">
          <SortableContext items={ranking} strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}>
            {ranking.map((rank) => (
              <SortableItem key={rank} id={rank} className="sortable-item" />
            ))}
          </SortableContext>
          <div className="button" style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <button
              className="btn submit-button"
              align="center"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(ranking);
              }}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </DndContext>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SortableItem.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

import { useSortable } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";
import {CSS} from "@dnd-kit/utilities";

export function SortableItem(props){
    //props.id
const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition
} = useSortable({id: props.id});

  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Transform.toString(transform),
    transition,
    marginBottom: "1rem",
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={style}
      {...attributes}
      {...listeners}
      className="hover-card"
    >
      <Card body>{props.id}</Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using useTransform, useref, giving dimension to the card, also tried using responsive css but it didnt work as expected.

PS, i am very new to reactjs

Thank you

Sitashma

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the transform and transition properties of the sortable items using the `useTransform` hook. This hook allows you to apply custom transformations to draggable elements based on their position or state. For example, you can modify your `SortableItem.jsx` file like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

import { useSortable, useTransform } from "@dnd-kit/sortable";

export function SortableItem(props) {
  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition,
    isDragging,
  } = useSortable({ id: props.id });

  const style = useTransform(
    transform,
    (transform) => {
      if (isDragging) {
        return {
          ...transform,
          width: "auto",
          height: "auto",
          margin: "1rem",
          boxShadow: "0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
        };
      }
      return {
        ...transform,
        transition,
      };
    },
    [isDragging]
  );

  return (
    <div
      ref={setNodeRef}
      style={style}
      {...attributes}
      {...listeners}
      className="hover-card"
    >
      <Card body>{props.id}</Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In styles as a value of transform you should use `CSS.Translate.toString(transform)` not `CSS.Transform.toString(transform)`.

```
  const style = {
    transform: CSS.Translate.toString(transform),
    transition,
    marginBottom: "1rem",
  };
```

Here you can find it:
https://github.com/clauderic/dnd-kit/issues/117

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion on GitHub fixed it for me](https://github.com/clauderic/dnd-kit/issues/117):

> The items are stretched because you're using CSS.Transform.toString(),
> use CSS.Translate.toString() if you don't want to have the scale
> transformation applied.